# MS Access: Disabling Navigation Buttons

Tags: forms, vba, database-design, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have to create a database for a one off work project and everyone has decided to use access as it is already installed on every machine. Now I'm new to access and new to databases in general so this has been a bit of a struggle. Still I'm getting there and have managed to make all the tables, set up relationships between them and create basically all the forms, but seem to have fallen at the last hurdle.

We have lots of different sites, each of which has lots of different rooms. What I am struggling with is the form for rooms. This is loaded from the site form. So site A will bring up a form with all the rooms in site A. The form can be loaded in read only, modify, or new record modes.

The problem is with the navigation buttons at the bottom. If you click new record using the navigation button then access creates a new record, but it loses the FK reference to the previous site. I have put a 'sort of' fix on this by making the FK on the form a combobox, so it can be corrected, but there are 40 sites so it isn't very elegant and isn't the behaviour anyone would expect.

To try and get around it I decided to try and build my own version of the access navigation controls, and eventually (with a lot of help from previous questions on stackoverflow) I succeeded and at the bottom of the form you can go to the first record, previous record, next record, last record, add a new record (keeping the FK reference) and even search through the loaded records in the recordset.

However all that becomes useless the moment I switch off the navigation controls. As soon as I set that to off for whatever reason access only loads the first record in the record set. So if site A has 10 rooms you only see room 1, and the controls I made (which work perfectly with navigation controls on) stop working, and furthermore the textbox I set up to mimic the '1 of 10' record number indicator changes to '1 of 1' making it clear that none of the other records are accessible.

This is really frustrating as it means I can only use my custom navigation controls by keeping Access's turned on. I don't want the access one turned on as it creates problems every time a new record is created.

So, after that long introduction, my question is: Why is access only loading the first record with navigation controls off, is there a way to stop this happening, and if not, can I just disable the new record bit of the navigation control?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I am sure it is a very simple thing, but googling has turned up nothing, and actually from what I have read I'm not even sure disabling navigation controls normally does this which makes the whole thing all the more depressing as this is literally the only form I don't want them on.

Thanks,

Dean

Answer (score 0):

If your only reason to add your own navigation controls was that you couldn't have the FK in you rooms form filled, I would keep the access navigation controls and set the FK in the Form_BeforeInsert() trigger of your rooms forms with something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me!FK = forms!Sites!PK
End Sub
```

If you would like to keep your own navigation controls, it would be helpful, to see your code to be able to answer your question.